# Transfer content of one array to another, removing duplicates

Tags: c#

I have an array of about 1000 words. I want to transfer them to another array while removing any duplicates. How can I do this in C# ?

Comment: Google a bit, there are plenty of posts around that do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question almost is the answer:

```
var array2 = array1.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: I cannot run that script in PHP due to timeout errors, better i run it in C# but its been ages since i touched C#, last time C# spec 1.0 was still new.